# CSS increase width using calc() does not affect parent container

Tags: html, css

Take a look at the following snippet. How can I **increase** the width of the red container with 10px?

Is there a way to increase the width of an element in CSS, still affecting the parent container? Or do I have to use a pseudo-element placeholder to accomplish this instead?

```html
<div style="
     background:blue;
     display:inline-block;
     height:50px">
 <div style="
     font-size:30px;
     width:calc(100% + 20px);
     background:red">
     Inner container</div>
</div>
```

In the snippet above the blue container is not affected, and the red overflows.

Comment: You are explicitly making the child 100% of the width of the parent + 20px. It can't be different, I mean, if the parent grows, the child would need to grow to be 20px bigger than that...

Comment: Why do you not use padding ?

Comment: Maybe you should take a quick browse through http://learnlayout.com/.

Comment: @AramilRey I know my example doesn't work for this reason, but is there a way to increase the width of an element?

Comment: @Imaginaerum I can't use padding in my use case.

Comment: @Roope I have read that page before

Comment: What are you trying to do?
What is your exact task?

Comment: @WinK- I want to increase the with of an element runtime with CSS (I can do it in JS already, by measuring, and then adding)

Comment: But if you want the parent to grow the same of child, why no increase the parent and have the child be always `100%` ? On what event do you want to increase the width ?

Comment: This seems a lot like a classic XY problem.

Comment: @estebanrincon The parent is just there to wrap the contents. The child itself have a width that is not known until runtime.

Comment: @Roope I'm not trying to solve an actual problem, I'm asking this because of curiousity: Is there a way to increase width of an element by a certain amount, where the width of the element itself is not known until runtime? Please refrain from making RTFM-style comments if you are not interested in this, look at other questions instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to increase width of an element by a certain amount, where the width of the element itself is not known until runtime?

You can only reliably do this using padding; however, padding will affect the layout of the element's contents, which may not be what you want. In your example, padding the child element will affect the layout of the text inside it; the content width is never really increased at all.

You can't change an element's content width by a definite amount when it is not known in advance and depends on external factors such as the amount of content it actually has, which is usually the case with floats, absolutely positioned elements, and inline-blocks. The closest you can get is an auto width, and that only has a meaningful effect on in-flow block boxes — which are none of the above — with respect to their *parents*, not their children.

In fact, the behavior that you see with `calc(100% + 20px)` is [not governed by the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#the-width-property), although it's as far as browsers generally go without falling into the cyclic dependency trap:

> **<percentage>**
>   Specifies a percentage width. The percentage is calculated with respect to the width of the generated box's containing block. If the containing block's width depends on this element's width, then the resulting layout is undefined in CSS 2.1.

(`calc()` is CSS3, but the box model hasn't changed much from CSS2.1.)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to increase the child's initial width and add another `10px`.

But when you set this property:
The `width: 100%` will always be relative to its parent, so if you add another `10px` in relation to the `100%` it will **always** be `10px` bigger than its parent.

You may want to set just a `min-width` and a `max-width` instead of setting explicitly its `width` so that the child will be within some specified ranges, but to increase the width by `10px` from the starting witdh using **JUST CSS**  its not possible.

**Note:** *Keep in min that using `calc`* you have to add the according `browser-engine property extension` i.e:

```
-webkit-calc()
-moz-calc()
calc()
```

```html
<div style="
     background:blue;
     display:inline-block;
     height:50px">
 <div style="
     font-size:30px;
     width: 100%; 
     background:red">
     Inner container</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps in some way, gl.